# Intuition to the Resolution of a fractional factorial design

Tags: experiment-design, intuition, definition, confounding, fractional-factorial

In design of experiments, is there an intuitive way to understand (and explain) the idea of the "resolution" of the design?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The concept of resolution is applied to fractional factorial experiments. Following the excellent [Statistics for Experimenters: Design, Innovation, and Discovery, 2nd Edition](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0471718130), for a half-design (that is, using one half of a full facorial deign), **the *resolution* is the length (number of letters in) its *generating relation***. For quarter-design, with two words in its generating relation, it would be the length of the shortest word, and similarly for smaller fractions.

For instance, a full factorial design on three (two-level) factors, denoted A, B, C, we could define a half-fraction by C=AB. Multiplying through with C this is equivalent with e (identity element, or vector of only ones)=ABC, which is the generating relation, of length three, so resolution III. The form C=AB shows that the main effect of C is aliased with the interaction AB, showing that this design is mostly useful if we can assume no interactions.

So, intuitively, we can say

- Resolution III, some main effects aliased with two-factor interactions.
- Resolution IV, some main effects aliased with three-factor interactions, and some two-factor interactions aliased with other two-factor interactions.
- Resolution V, some main effects aliased with four-factor interactions, some two-factor interactions aliased with three-factor interactions, but never with other two-factor interactions, ...